# Why do we delete questions that are closed here in the workplace?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I think there should not be any reason to delete closed questions just because they sound the same as another question.

If this is a technical stack exchange then yes I think duplicate questions with the same single answer can be deleted because in a sense the answers are just repeating.

But for the workplace, I think this is not applicable. A lot of people answer the same question, but there are instances that the answers are totally different and provide different views which to the OP and other readers and I think is beneficial for the whole network.

There are a lot of people providing good insights on how they would answer a question or what they think of the question. It would be a shame to just have them deleted because they appeared in a question that sounds like a previously asked question. Last time I checked, stackexchange provides answers, not delete them.

Comment: As Kilisi suggest, it would be helpful to link to a specific instance of this. You should be able to find a list of your deleted posts by searching for `deleted:yes`

Comment: Are you actually meaning deleted? Or just closed. Those are two VERY different things. Generally dupes are CLOSED not deleted. It would have to be a bigger issue than just being a duplicate to cause a deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show an example of this? We don't delete duplicates just because they're duplicates, we mark them as such and link them.

That's the theory anyway, as I understand it.

Comment: Agreed. In general the questions that get deleted tend to be poorly written or have zero answers.

Answer (score -2):

This site has high traffic, it's our best interests to filter out noise. We don't need anything but good quality questions.

Closed questions are inappropriate and take significant disk space to keep. Why do you want to keep rubbish?

Comment: For the technicality, nothing is hard-deleted on Stack Exchange though (the "take significant disk space" argument is irrelevant)... deleted posts are still visible for those who have ["access to moderator tools"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege...

Comment: what is the difference of rubbish and not rubbish? also, I'm referring to solid answers that provide a different view for all the readers, but in the end are being deleted since they are part of a duplicate question.